# TypeError - wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module) - Eager Loading Association - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Could one advise me where i am going wrong

in my view file i have the below code

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <% CategoryOutsourceadvert.include(:advert).all do |categoryoutsourceadvert| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag('q[category_outsourceadverts_id_eq_any][]', categoryoutsourceadvert.id ) %>
        <%= categoryoutsourceadvert.name %> (<%= categoryoutsourceadvert.adverts.uniq.count %>)
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Model

```
Advert belongs_to category_outsourceadvert
CategoryOutsourceadvert has_many adverts
```

In my Terminal i get an error i don't understand:

```
TypeError - wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module):
  app/views/adverts/_index.html.erb:134:in `block in _app_views_adverts__index_html_erb___100043438257983213_70223712632760'
```

> Could one kindly explain to me what this error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace includes with joins, so it looks like this `CategoryOutsourceadvert.joins(:advert).all`

Comment: awesome!! Thank you soo much!

Comment: `includes` and `joins` should be used for different purposes. Replacing one for the other is often not desirable.

Comment: Yeah and this was a case for using joins, as it also resolved his issue

Answer (score 9):

You forgot the 's':

```
CategoryOutsourceadvert.includes(:advert).all
```

Comment: Would it make a difference if I had it on something like this? What would differentiate `include` vs `includes` in this cast? `scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :posts, sub_categories: :posts }`